# $x\notin X\setminus\{y\} \iff x\notin X$ or $x=y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is the following deduction correct?

$$\begin{align} x\notin X\setminus\{y\}\quad & \iff\quad x\notin X \cap \overline{\{y\}}\\ \\
& \iff\quad x \in \overline{X\cap \overline{\{y\}}}\\ \\
& \iff\quad x \in \overline X \cup \{y\}\\ \\ 
& \iff\quad x \notin X\text{ or } x =y\end{align}$$

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I would **strongly** advise against using $\overline{X}$ to denote the complement - it denotes the closure - but apart from that, I see nothing to criticize.

Comment: What about the obvious $x\in X\setminus\{y\}\iff x\in X \land x\neq y$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the deduction is correct, but it's important to clarify what you're doing and why it holds (particularly when submitting for homework, and/or writing an exam!)

So I'd suggest adding more ***words***, if only to add *justification*. For e.g., you use DeMorgan's when going from the third to fourth line: $$\quad x \in \overline{X\cap \overline{\{y\}}} \iff x \in \overline X \cup \{y\}\tag{DeMorgan's}$$ Say so!

Answer (score 0):

What you did is fine but I'd negate both sides and then it's obvious by definition:
$$
x\in X\setminus\{y\} \iff x\in X \text{ and } x\ne y
$$

Of course, De Morgan's law is present in the form *not (P or Q)* is the same as *(not P) and (not Q)*.